# $\mathfrak{h}\subsetneq \operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{exp}(h))$ possible?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

consider $G$ a Lie group and the exponential map $\operatorname{exp} : \operatorname{Lie}(G)\to G$. Now let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Lie-subalgebra of Lie(G). I more or less understand that $\mathfrak{h}\subset \operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{exp}(h))$ but is it possible that $\mathfrak{h}\subsetneq \operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{exp}(h))$?

Comment: It should be $\langle exp (\mathfrak{h})\rangle$ - the image of the exponent might not be a subgroup. And I'm pretty sure this is impossible.

Comment: Yes, this is impossible - the proof should be in most books about Lie groups, I think.